# catalina log filled with fake ClassNotFoundException for custom log4j Appender, everything else working fine

Tags: log4j

I am getting error in catalina.out of tomcat server

```
:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cloudstack.syslog.AlertsSyslogAppender
         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:247)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.java:436)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:999)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.doOnChange(DOMConfigurator.java:1120)
         at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.checkAndConfigure(FileWatchdog.java:89)
         at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.<init>(FileWatchdog.java:58)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.<init>(DOMConfigurator.java:1112)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(DOMConfigurator.java:735)
         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(DOMConfigurator.java:718)
         at com.cloud.utils.LogUtils.initLog4j(LogUtils.java:32)
        at com.cloud.bridge.service.EC2MainServlet.init(EC2MainServlet.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
```

Functionality wise everything is working fine, i.e. my custom appender  is getting called and doing what ever is written in that custom appender. But in catalina.out above error messages are comming periodically, if I make some modification in log4j.xml.  What could be the possible error.

Answer (score 0):

You `log4j` configuration mention `org.apache.cloudstack.syslog.AlertsSyslogAppender` but related `jar` ([`apache-cloudstack`](http://cloudstack.apache.org/index.html)) is not on `classpath`

Comment: which classpath you are talking about?

Comment: webapp, if you are not sure on classpath configuration on Tomcat checkout http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath#solutions

Comment: I have already checked that. Mine problem is this error(only in catalina.out log) starts coming if I modify log4j.xml. Other then it is working fine. Even though it is showing error in catalina.out there is no such error. i.e cloudtsack doesn't show any error in its management server log

Comment: In other words required jar is present in webapp and it is getting called also, only fake messages of ClassNotFoundException are coming in catalina.out